# Pygit2: Need help on how to walk on all commits in all repo's branches

Tags: python-3.x, pygit2

I'd need to walk on entire repo's branches commits. I have tried this but with no success. :

```
for branch_name in list(repo.branches.remote):
   try:
        branch = repo.lookup_branch(branch_name)
        ref = repo.lookup_reference(branch.name)
        repo.checkout(ref)

        for commit in repo.walk(branch.target, pygit2.GIT_SORT_TIME):
            print(commit.id.hex)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have:

```py
def iterate_repository(dir: str) -> None:
    repo = pygit2.Repository(dir)
    for branch_name in list(repo.branches.remote):
        branch = repo.branches.get(branch_name)
        latest_commit_id = branch.target
        latest_commit = repo.revparse_single(latest_commit_id.hex)

        for commit in repo.walk(latest_commit.id, pygit2.GIT_SORT_TIME):
            print(commit.id.hex)
```

Expanding from that should be relatively easy. What I do is gather statistics from files included in a commit.

Comment: This code sometimes raises `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'hex'`. `branch.target` sometimes has type `str`.